# how download Mysql database to Sqlite database

Tags: android

I have a Mysql database which has 8 tables now I want to create a button and by clicking this button all data of Mysql is insert to Sqlit like download.
how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is transform you mysql data to json and then parse it and insert to sqlite